# Linux: Merge files from different servers

Tags: bash, concatenation

I have 3 Linux servers and in each server I have a folder with a few files in it. From one of the server, I would need to access the files present in current server's folder and the files present in other 2 server's folder and concatenate them.

I am able to concatenate two or more files within a folder or subfolder in a single Linux server. Need help in doing the same across servers.

That is:
Input Files from 3 servers:
server1/folder1/file1;
server2/folder1/file1;
server3/folder1/file1;

Output File:
server1/folder1/file1 (Contains the contents of the 3 servers)

Similarly I would need to do it for file2, file3 etc., within the same folder.

Is this possible to write a shell script for the same using ssh and cat?

Comment: And to answer your question: yes, it is possible. Are you expecting people to write it for you? :)

Comment: If you start by writing the code logic in pseudo-code, fine-grained for each task that you are trying to accomplish, in the correct sequence and in the correct context, then having that worded so that it does exactly what you want it to do will, almost explicitly, tell you WHAT you need to code for each of those, not the HOW. The HOW is the nitty gritty of coding. What you have outlined above in your question does not demonstrate that level of detail on the task breakdown. If you give that a try, the solution will almost pop out of the page at you. Good luck with your apprenticeship!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I think it. Non *indempotent*:
If you run twice, you will grow up the current file accordingly.

You need `ssh-key pair` and `ssh-agent` to run.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eox pipefail

servers=( server{1..3} )
files=( folder1/file{1..3} )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
        ssh "$server cat $file" >> "$file"
    done
done
```

**Answered to teach you good bash coding habits.**
We saw so many boring broken RealLife©®™ shell scripts there.

Quoting properly is one of the key of shell scripting.

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words